# Apache Shiro; SecurityUtils.getSubject() for a schedule user?

Tags: shiro

I want to implement the following scenario:
I have a EJB scheduler, which should run every 1 minute.

My issue is the following:
I need a login for the user, who execute the schedule. This should be a system user. There will be no login via GUI.

How can I login this user and execute further task?
Currently I´m trying in my class:

```
    @Singleton
    @LocalBean
    @Startup
    public class Scheduler {
        

public void startSchedule() {
    Subject currentUserShiro = SecurityUtils..getSubject();
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("test@domain.com", "test1234");
    currentUserShiro.login(token);
```

In one of my function, I check e.g. for the permission:

```
SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("billingInvoice:create")
```

I´m getting currently the following issue:

> No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.

Any idea?

---

Code update:

```
    private void addScheduleToList(ScheduleExecution scheduleExecution) throws UnknownHostException {

    synchronized (this) {

        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro-web.ini");
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        Subject subject = new Subject.Builder().buildSubject();

        Runnable myRunnable = null;

        subject.execute(myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    // Add tasks
                    executeAction(scheduleExecution);
             }
        });

        //////
        schedulingService.addTaskToExecutor(taskId, myRunnable, 0);

    }

}
```

I´m gettig now not anymore the issue message which I got initialy, but it seems I´m getting PermissionException, because the user has not the permission? If I check the Subject object, this object is not authenticated. This Subject object needs full permission. How can I do this?

SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("billingInvoice:create") == false

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. Move your permission checking to your web-based methods, this moves the permission checkout outside of your scheduled task.
   (this isn't always possible and since you are asking the question, I'm assuming you want the 2nd option)
2. You need to execute your task in the context of a user.  Create a new Subject using a SubjectBuilder and then call the `execute` with a runnable from your task.

See https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html specifically the "Thread Association" section.

Comment: Thanks, I´ve updated my code... but I got still the same issue... Any ideas?

Comment: Now you have a permission issue, which is expected because you didn't grant your user.  IIRC, you can just set the 'authenticated' flag on the Subject builder.  Dealing with permissions, starts to fall into application-specific code.

You could create a simple Realm, to assign permissions to this user, or use an existing one you have configured.  Do you want to manage permissions for this "system" user with your other users? or do you want to use a separate data store?

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you... Ok I understood. But how can I assign the permissions to the Subject object? I cannot see any set function on the Subject object?

Comment: My current code: `Subject.Builder subjectBuilder = new Subject.Builder();
   subjectBuilder.authenticated(true);
   Subject subject = subjectBuilder.buildSubject();`